# Cannot unwrap optional value to label

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am new to this board. Please, excuse my bad english in advance.

I am trying to send a string from a subview to his parent view. If I try to set that string to a label, my app crashes with the message "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

Example code from the subview:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    sendDataToVc("test")

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func sendDataToVc(myString : String) {

    let Vc = ViewController()
    Vc.dataFromContainer(myString)
}
```

Example from the parent view:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
var cacheStr1 : String!
var cacheStr2 : String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    label1.text = ""
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func dataFromContainer(containerData : String){


    label1.text = cacheStr1


}

@IBAction func changeLabel(sender: AnyObject) {



}
```

I have no more ideas what I am doing wrong. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
let Vc = ViewController()
```

You are *creating a new instance* — a new ViewController instance. That's not what you want to do. You want to get a reference to an *existing* instance — the one that is your view controller's parent view controller, if that's what a View Controller is in relation to your TableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You better instance your `ViewController` form `StoryBoard` and define what you want to pass as property, and then set this property to the value that you need to show, and in the viewDidLoad of your `ViewController` update your view as you need